# Config settings for securing Elasticsearch with Nginx

Tags: nginx, elasticsearch, kibana

I am running Kibana 1.3 and ElasticSearch 1.4 on the same host and I have installed Nginx in an attempt to keep connections to ES locally. To browse Kibana remotely, I have also registered a dynamic DNS domain name and bind it with the host on which Kibana and ElasticSearch are running on e.g. http://example.no-ip.org.

I think the use of dynamic DNS domain name has caused problems with connectionbetween Kibana and ES and I'm not sure how the configurations should be set so that:

1) *only* Kibana can communicate with ElasticSearch and on a local-basis
2) ElasticSearch API is not exposed to the world.

The guide I followed is: http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/playing-http-tricks-nginx/

Here's the config for Nginx:

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

  upstream elasticsearch {
  server 127.0.0.1:9200;
  server 127.0.0.1:9201;
  server 127.0.0.1:9202;

  keepalive 15;
}

server {
   listen 8080;

   location / {
     proxy_pass http://elasticsearch;
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header Connection "Keep-Alive";
     proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection "Keep-Alive";
   }

 }

}
```

And here's the config settings I added in elasticsearch.yml:

```
network.host: "127.0.0.1"
http.host: "127.0.0.1"
http.cors.allow-origin: "/.*/"
http.cors.enabled: true
```

As for Kibana, I have changed the default settings to use port 8080:

```
elasticsearch: "http://" + window.location.hostname + ":8080",
```

Thank you very much for your help in advance!